# Should a class explicitly implement interface if its superclass also implements it?

Tags: java, coding-style

Given an interface

```
interface I {
    one();
    two();
}
```

An abstract base class partially implementing `I`

```
abstract class A {
    @Override
    void one() {
         //something
    }
}
```

And lastly a subclass of `A`

```
class B extends A (implements I) {
     @OVerride
     void two() {
         //something
    }
}
```

And now `B` has to implement `I` since `A` did.

In the `B` class I have (implements `I`) and my question is,
is it good coding style to explicitly mention that you implement `I`?
Even though that's given implicitly by the fact that you're subclassing `A`, that's partially implementing `I`?

Please note this is a question about good style. I know there is no difference between the two approaches, language-wise.

Comment: While your questions hasn't been closed, you might want to consider [Why was my question closed as primarily opinion-based?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6491/). Your question is very close to being more about opinion than expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I don't have an authoritative answer, in my experience it would depend on the situation.

Usually, the redundancy is unneeded. The main point here is readability, and shorter is typically better. And, as you've already mentioned in the question, there's no functional difference, so write whichever one better fits the logic of the model and will make it easier to understand.

From time to time, including the redundant interface can be useful. Here's a version (using the `Animal`->`Cat` classes) of one time I left it in:

```
interface Animal {}
interface DomesticAnimal implements Animal {}

abstract class AbstractMammal implements Animal {}
class ConcreteDolphin extends AbstractMammal {}
abstract class AbstractCat extends AbstractMammal implements Animal {}
class DomesticCat extends AbstractCat implements DomesticAnimal {}
class WildCat extends AbstractCat {}
```

A bit of context: In that particular case my task was to implement some new functionality in the new `ConcreteDolphin` and `AbstractMammal` classes and refactor a bit of common code in the abstract class.

However, my team was already used to working with `Animal`s, and `AbstractMammal`s were still a fairly new concept. After all, everyone knows that a `Cat` must be an `Animal`; what was this `AbstractMammal` nonsense?!

Thus in this case I thought it was better to leave the redundant `AbstractCat  extends AbstractMammal implements Animal` as it made it easier to read. I'd say this is a somewhat **rare case**, though, most times it would be cleaner to only have the one.

Comment: +1 but wouldn't a concrete dolphin sink?